# how to make post section work in the same node as stage section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a question. 
Since I'm a beginner in jenkins declarative pipeline.

I have the following script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {           
        stage('verification test') {
           steps {
               node ('SERVER') {
                   script {
                       echo "> modifying Junit files and put in junit\output folder"
                   } //script
               } //node
            }//steps
            post {
                always {                 
                    script {
                        echo " > current workspace : ${WORKSPACE}
                        echo " > publish Junit from junit\output "
                        junit testResults: '**/junit/output/*.xml'
                    }
                }
            }
        } //stage
    } //stages
} //pipeline
```

when I execute the pipeline, the post section always running in different node as the steps section. So Junit file always can't be found. I tried different combination on the position of the Junit as well as the post section but it seems I still can't get it right.

Anything I missed on the declaration?
My purpose is to have stage section (preparing junit files) & the post section (publish Junit file) in the same node.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you allocating yet another agent here with `node ('SERVER')`? Why not put the label on top (`agent  { label 'SERVER' }`)? This would avoid allocating yet another build agent.

Answer (score 0):

To copy over data from one build agent to another, you can use [`stash` and `unstash`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-%20stash%20some%20files%20to%20be%20used%20later%20in%20the%20build):